# Cannot find software on Microsoft BizSpark

Tags: msdn, bizspark

I work for a company that is a member of Microsoft BizSpark. I have a Windows Live ID, and I can use this to log in at bizspark.com. However, I cannot for the life of me find out how to download software from the site! I am looking for Visual Studio Professional and Microsoft Office, in particular. Do I need further credentials, and if so, how do I get them?

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 94, accepted):

The page for subscriber downloads is: https://my.visualstudio.com/productkeys

Comment: Thank you so much! The bizspark site is so frustrating for not having this information

Comment: Your website is bad if people find content by using another website.

Comment: This thread is my official bookmark for the downloads page :)

Comment: The latest link is shown in this answer https://stackoverflow.com/a/46653171/80428

Answer (score 4):

You can now go to
[my.visualstudio.com](https://my.visualstudio.com/)

Once logged in, the "downloads" and "Keys" links are conveniently at the top of the page.

Answer (score 3):

For those still struggling, this may help:

1. open new **incognito window** ( in chrome or mozila ) and go to link from received mail ( https://www.microsoft.com/bizspark ) ->  log in with the mail address from received mail and proper password
2. click "My BizSpark" ( the middle of the page ) from the menu. Now your screen should look like this.

[image]

3. Go to https://msdn.microsoft.com and log in to your account - > when you are in click "My Account" from menu - > then click "activate your account" - > and fill in data from bizspark site (image above).
   Done